# Missing EC2 CPU metrics datapoints Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am havinhg a weird pronblem, I have missing CPU datapoints in Cloudwatch AWS for CPU metrics. These metrics are supplied by AWS and my alarams go crazy for nothing.

[image: EC2 CPU utilization]
I have recently changed the instances from t2 to t3a.

Also this problem **only appears on my t3a.nano** instances, not for t3a.medium and t3a.small instances.

The problem is not that zero values are not send, here is an example including zero values:
[image: zero values are present]

Also I can see, that my memory metrics which a sent by a cronjob on the EC2 instance are normal and not missing, so the instance was working.

Any Idea, what the problem might be?

Comment: Are these the native CPU metrics? If so these are sent from the underlying host. You could try stop starting which will migrate your server to another physical host.

Comment: It might be that zero-values are not send to CloudWatch. I know this is the case for SQS queue size, not sure for EC2 CPUUtilization.

Comment: i have checked the zero values, here are zero values in the metrics. The physical host is also not the problem, i have multiple instances which have this problem. I think this is a aws bug.

Answer (score 0):

My dirty solution was to change my CloudWatch alarms to **ignore** missing data:

Docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html#alarms-and-missing-data